# How to pause a OpenCV video video stream to get points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have an OpenCV loop running with a video. I want to pause the video on the second frame and make the user click on two points.

```
import time
import cv2

points=[]
layer = 0
def onMouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if len(points) < 2:
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            points.append((x,y))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
while cap.isOpened():
    layer +=1
    ret, im = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow(win, im)
        key = cv2.waitKey(100)

        if len(points) < 2 and layer==2:
            cv2.setMouseCallback(win, onMouse)        

        if key == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the previous code doesn't pause for user input.

if I try:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Whole program freezes.

I've also tried the using a while loop inside a while loop but it also freezes

```
if layer == 2:
    while len(points) < 2:
        cv2.setMouseCallback(win, onMouse)
        if len(points) == 2:
            break
```

What Can I do to pause for the user to input two clicks

Comment: setMouseCallback only has to be called once.

Comment: @Micka Understood and thank you but it doesn't really solve my issue.

Comment: did you change it? I could imagine, that multiple setMouseCallbacks could lead to freezes, since many openCV gui problems lead to feeezes. Should should set the callback outside of the loop. You could add print in the loop and in the callback, to easily find out where it is stuck and whether the callback is activated at all.

Comment: @Micka Yes, just tested it with only one setMouseCallback outside the while loop. Even with multiple setMouseCallback it runs fine but when I try to pause to a frame using `time.sleep` or while loop, it freezes. I just need a way to pause to a frame without pausing the event loop of OpenCV.

Comment: waitKey(0), if an opencv window is present. a repeated waitKey(100) will work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seemed to work for me.

```
if layer == 2:
    cv2.setMouseCallback(win, onMouse)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[how-should-i-properly-use-cv2-waitkey-when-wanting-to-start-pause-a-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638463/how-should-i-properly-use-cv2-waitkey-when-wanting-to-start-pause-a-video)

But any suggestion on how to escape the wait key if there are two points in the list?

Comment: while(whatever) cv2.waitKey(100)